# Restarting a libGDX game to apply changes to resolution

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I restart a LibGDX game to apply certain changes to the game such as changes to the resolution (going from 1920X1080 to 1280X720), or changing full screen.
Granted the `resize(int width, int height)` can help with the resolution change, but I need to change other settings as well so I rather restart the game and continue from the options menu instead of forcing the user to manually exit the game and then restart it.

Answer (score 3):

After 3 days of working I managed to work around it, I created this git repository so people can use it, it says everything there.
[Git Repository](https://github.com/AonGoltzCrank/LibGDX-Class-Connector)
Enjoy, those who need it.

EDIT: Not the solution.
EDIT: The solution is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467014/closing-a-threads-gui-after-using-runtime-exec).

Comment: Can you quote the relevant part of your code here, in case you delete your repository later? That way, people on this site can still see how you did it.

Comment: Sure, give me a minute.

Comment: I am not approving this  because of the fact this while it gives you  the DesktopLauncher class, you still can not restart the game due to an error, I'll post a new problem since it's a different issue, and once I have that resolved I'll come back and change it to the complete answer.

Comment: This is too much code to be useful, instead of just the part relevant to the question.

Comment: Like I said, this isn't the answer, so once I have the answer I'll write it, for now I'm removing the code, whoever wants the code it's in the repository.

Comment: Found the solution, editing.